# Is there an option to search in memory tool in Android Studio?

Tags: android, memory, android-studio, memoryanalyzer

It's amazing that memory analyzing tools are integrated in the Android studio 1.3 - But one of the main features regarding the memory dump is the ability to search by class name (to see how many instances of an activity exist).
This option (available in MAT for example) is missing in Android Studio and crippling it.

Does anyone know if it exists and I missed it?

Is it planned?